# How to place borde around transparent PNG in Gravit.io?

Tags: borders

I've got a Transparent PNG and want to put a 1px border around the visible part of the image.

When I try to add a Border in Gravit.io   it puts the border around the outside of the rectangle (the whole png)

Comment: Never used Gravit.. but it appears to be a **vector** application. Typically *vector* apps see PNG files as *one* object and although the PNG may contain transparent pixels, it's the boundaries of the actual image (the outer rectangle) the vector app detects, and *not* the non-transparent pixels within those boundaries. At least this is true for Illustrator (and I believe Inkscape as well.)

Comment: @Scott - I agree. If it's a vector image editor, then it's likely not possible, at least not directly/automatically. It could be done very easily in a raster image editor such as Photoshop or GIMP though - then just export as PNG again.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. What's confusing is that Gravit.io will see the edges of non-transparent pixels as the boundary for *some* things like "drop shadow" but not for others (like Border)

Comment: Illustrator's the same. I think it's because the basic under-the-hood process for drop shadows is to copy, rasterize, greyscale, blur, place below original object -- so the transparency is simply built into the rasterization step for shadows and glows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the PNG to a SVG with something like: https://png-to-svg.com/